# how to remove flickr from qcameraviewfinder widget

Tags: c++, qt5

I have placed 4 qcameraviewfinder widgets on a widget.so that output of 4 cameras are visible at a time. But when I toggle between any one of them to fullscreen and back to normal , it gives a lot of flicker while repainting all four widgets. Any idea how to reduce it?

Answer (score 0):

I have used qgraphicsview with qgraphicsscene and the flicker is gone.